# set calendar view to default month view

Tags: lightning, admin

Is there any way to set calendar view to default month view. if there is any, kindly help me to solve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer this document link :-

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuqzQAC

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LnYGQA0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.